# radio buttons appearing without labels in table column using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create radio buttons dynamically. And then adding those radio buttons in table column. Code is working but radio button is appearing without labels. Here is the code snippet

```
var $td = $('<td></td>');
for(i=0; i<factorOptions.length; i++){
    var checked = false;
    var factorOption = factorOptions[i];
    if (factorOption.toUpperCase() === selectedFactor.toUpperCase()) {
        checked = true
    }

    var $radioInput = $('<input />', { 
        type: 'radio', 
        id: ruleId +'-factor-' + i, 
        name: ruleId +'-factor',
        'value': factorOption,
        'checked': checked,
        'text' : factorOption
    });
    $radioInput.before($("<label />")
        .attr("for", $radioInput.attr("id"))
        .text($radioInput.val()));
    $td.append($radioInput);                
}
```

I tried with `$radioInput.after()` also but result is same. What I am doing wrong ?
When I am see the column in browser it looks like this

```
<td>
    <input name="1-factor" id="1-factor-0" type="radio" value="Once">
    <input name="1-factor" id="1-factor-1" type="radio" checked="checked" value="Each">
</td>
```

Thanks

Comment: provide a working plunkr for this so that it is easy to reproduce the error and solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be just calling `.append` to soon:

```
var $radioInput = $('<input />', { 
    type: 'radio', 
    id: ruleId +'-factor-' + i, 
    name: ruleId +'-factor',
    'value': factorOption,
    'checked': checked,
    'text' : factorOption
});

$td.append($radioInput); // add it here

$radioInput.before($("<label />")
    .attr("for", $radioInput.attr("id"))
    .text($radioInput.val()));
// $td.append($radioInput); remove from here
```

You need the input to be appended before you add the labels using `.before`

Simplified [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5ms99vo/1/)